# RecyclerView doesn't appear when go into fragment for second time with Jetpack Navigation Component

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have a Fragment with inside a RecyclerView. I obtain the data for the `RecyclerView` with a SQL Request that I call in `OnViewCreated`.

When I go into this fragment for the first time, the `RecyclerView` appears normally, but if I leave this `Fragment` (by back button), and go again into this `Fragment`, the `RecyclerView` doesn't appear. So the RecyclerView appears only one time.

Below is some codes :

```
private var itemArray = arrayListOf<Item>()
private lateinit var itemRecycler: RecyclerView
private lateinit var itemAdapter: ItemAdapter
```

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_fragment, container, false)

        itemRecycler = view.findViewById(R.id.item_recycler)

        return  view
    }
```

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    populateItemArray {

        // Init Adapter
        itemAdapter = ItemAdapter(itemArray)

        // Set adapter to recycler
        itemRecycler.apply {
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context!!, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
            adapter = itemAdapter
        }

    }
}
```

```
private fun populateItemArray(completion: () -> Unit) {

    SQLiteManager(context!!).getItems() { defaultItemArray ->

        itemArray.addAll(defaultItemArray.filter { it.itemId == 67 })

        completion()
    }
}
```

Note: Each time I go into this fragment, I get a list with nearly 6 items.

I use `Jetpack Navigation Component`. I go into the `Fragment` first time where everything works normally, then go back to previous fragment by `BackButton`, then finally a go into the `Fragment` again like the first time, but the `RecyclerView` doesn't appear (other views appear normally).

**EDIT:**

It seems the problem is that the RecyclerView has `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`. When I use `match_parent`the RecyclerView appears. I've used `wrap_content`because I wanted to center the RecyclerView. Below the XML :

```xml
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/item_recycler"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/item_image"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/item_button"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                android:overScrollMode="never"/>
```

Note that when I set new LayoutParams like this

```
itemRecycler.layoutParams = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
```

The RecyclerView appear (but badly placed)

**SOLUTION:**

I've found the solution of this problem : I set again width of RecyclerView as wrap_content after set the Adapter :

```
val params = itemRecycler.layoutParams
        params.width = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        itemRecycler.layoutParams = params
        itemRecycler.requestLayout()
```

This solved the problem for me. Thank you for your help, I hope it can be useful for someone.

Sorry for my poor english, and thank you for your help

Comment: How do you "go in to this view"? What does that mechanism look like?

Comment: I use the Jetpack Navigation Component. I go into the Fragment a first time where everything works normally, then a back to previous fragment by backbutton, then finally a go into the Fragment again like the first time but there the recycler doesn't appear.

Comment: Are you sure at the moment of `adapter = itemAdapter` the adapter contains nonempty data? I also usually add `setHasFixedSize(true)`. You can try to set background and width, height to ensure that `RecyclerView` is empty.

Comment: have you tried moving your `populateItemArray` logic to onResume? Maybe for some reason view isn't recreated.

Comment: @r2rek Yes I've tried this but it doesn't work either

Comment: @CoolMind Yes I set ```adpater = itemAdapter```after have filled my itemArray. With a background, it seems the Recycler is empty the second time

Comment: show us the .xml layout, maybe we can figure it out since the problem is with wrap_content :)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by setting adapter again after fetching results from server

```
contactsAdapter = ContactsAdapter(this, readContactsArray)
contactsRecyclerView.adapter = contactsAdapter
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add    "RecyclerView.setAdapter(yourAdapter)"   after getting data

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).